# Changing the keys of as two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have a two dimensional array and I need to change the keys of the inner arrays as follows:

From:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => 1
            [B] => John
            [C] => Doe
            [D] => Mr
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => 2
            [B] => Jane
            [C] => Doe
            [D] => Mrs
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A] => 5
            [B] => Jill
            [C] => Smith
            [D] => Miss
        )
)
```

To:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [title] => Mr
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Jane
            [last_name] => Doe
            [title] => Mrs
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [first_name] => Jill
            [last_name] => Smith
            [title] => Miss
        )
)
```

Changing the values is straight forward, but I have no idea how to change the keys and can't find any useful suggestions. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why not create a desired new array  and assign it to the original one `original[0] = desired_sub_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will reformat and update old array:

```
$map = [
    'A' => 'id',
    'B' => 'first_name',
    'C' => 'last_name',
    'D' => 'title',
    
];

foreach($your_array as $key => &$innerArray) {
    $newInnerArray = [];
    
    foreach($innerArray as $ik => $iv) {
        $newInnerArray[$map[$ik]] = $iv;
    }
    
    
    $innerArray = $newInnerArray;   
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! The actual array is 1600 elements with 28 elements in the inner arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If there are always 4 items and the order does not change, you could create a `$keys` array and using [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) inside [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$keys = [
    "id",
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "title"
];
$array = [
    1 => ["A" => 1, "B" => "John", "C" => "Doe", "D" => "Mr"],
    2 => ["A" => 2, "B" => "Jane", "C" => "Doe", "D" => "Mrs"],
    3 => ["A" => 5, "B" => "Jill", "C" => "Smith", "D" => "Miss"],
];
$result = array_map(function ($x) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $x);
}, $array);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Doe
            [title] => Mr
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Jane
            [last_name] => Doe
            [title] => Mrs
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [first_name] => Jill
            [last_name] => Smith
            [title] => Miss
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/LVvn4)